# chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab captures wrong area

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I am trying to create chrome extension which will take a screenshot of a large page.

Here is a  my simple extension that should scroll to and capture some parts of a page.

manifest.json

```
    {

      "manifest_version": 2,
      "name": "screenshot_test",
      "version": "1.0",

      "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "<all_urls>"
      ],

      "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
      },

      "browser_action": {
        "default_icon":  "icon.png"
      }

    }
```

background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(capture)    
function capture(){

    function scroll(point, callback){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            code: 'window.scrollTo('+JSON.stringify((point.x))+','+JSON.stringify(point.y)+')',
        }, callback)
    }

    function capturetab(){
        chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(function(imageUri){
            shots.push(imageUri);
        });
    }

    var shots=[];
    var points=[{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 500, y: 500},{x: 1000, y: 1000}];

    for (var i=0; i<3; i++) scroll(points[i], capturetab);    
    console.log(shots);
}
```

The issue is that shots[], the array of imageuris, contains some identical imageuris, like if capturevisibletab captures the same area several times.

In firefox that exact same code works just fine, with the exception that in firefox capturevisibletab returns promise and callback is not an obligatory.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Your scroll() function assumes that the tab is scrolled before callback() is invoked.
There is no such guarantee because the API is asynchronous.
I guess it works for you now only because your FF still runs in single-process mode.

Specify the `callback` in executeScript so that it's called back after the script is actually executed.

```
  function scroll(point, callback){   
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
      code: 'window.scrollTo('+JSON.stringify((point.x))+','+JSON.stringify(point.y)+')'
    }, callback);
  }
```

Comment: Yes, the issue is that api is asynchronous, but your solution doesn't work either. I managed to solve this using setTimeout, but I believe this is not how it should be and looking for a better solution for synchronous calls.

Comment: Indeed, the need to use setTimeout seems hacky, and it might be a limitation or bug of chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab: it's possible that it simply reuses the last paint result, which isn't immediately updated by the renderer when window.scrollTo completes.